# Bootable USB doesn't work!

Tags: boot, live-usb, hp, bios

I am using Ubuntu for a couple of years in single boot. But for reason now I need to go back to windows. 
I have created a bootable usb with windows 10 ISO and reboot my device. After selecting USB from BIOS as booting device it doesn't boot into windows 10 and continues booting as Ubuntu. Now what should I do for installing Windows 10?
I use HP Notebook - 15-ay102tu with Intel HD graphics 660 and 4GB DDR4 RAM. My partition format is MBR (msdos) and I've tried to boot from BIOS.

Comment: If you made the USB with Ubuntu, you probably need to download and use WoeUSB to make a bootable Wndows USB.  Windows does not seem to like most other ways of doing it.

Comment: I've tried WoeUSB but didn't work on Ubuntu. Then I've created bootable USB using preinstalled disk tool

Comment: I recommend `woeusb` in text mode (with a command line) according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185) to another AskUbuntu question.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen for several reasons like gpt and mbr hard disk and uefi and legacy boot. To make sure everything is ok try following steps:

1) check hard disk is gpt or mbr 
you can find how [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387351/how-can-i-detect-whether-my-disk-is-using-gpt-or-mbr-from-a-terminal)

2) if gpt make sure your boot is set to uefi else set boot to legacy bios

3) download rufus program to burn the iso and make sure to select hard disk gpt or mbr

4) disable secure boot (You can enable it later)

5) boot usb and try installing windows 
rufus ([download link](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.8/rufus-3.8p.exe))

Comment: But rufus doesn't work on Ubuntu!  And also I've tried to boot from BIOS because of my MBR partition

Comment: I recommend you to do this on a friend computer using windows

Comment: You can try https://www.balena.io/etcher/

Answer (score 0):

I used `unetbootin` to make a bootable USB with Windows 10 on it some days ago. You can use `unetbootin` for Ubuntu, just simply install ist using [these](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) instructions.

`unetbootin` works very easily, you just need the .iso file of Windows.