# Ubuntu 18.04 is attempting to load the wrong vmlinuz file, how to fix?

Tags: boot

I have a machine with a 2 TB M.2 HD dual booted with Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 (still need 18.04 for legacy reasons, please don't ask for the details :).

I just did an update to 20.04 and now 18.04 won't boot without choosing a special option.  Here is my usual grub screen upon boot:

[image]

If I choose `Ubuntu 18.04` I get this:

[image]

If instead at the main boot menu I choose `Advanced options for Ubutnu 18.04.5 LTS (18.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)` I get this:

[image]

If I choose any of these non-recovery mode options everything boots and works normally.

What I don't understand is why is the usual boot option looking for kernel version ending in `70`?  It's not there anymore!  How can I make it look for one of the kernel versions that is there?

I did some more poking around, when I `ls` the contents of `/boot` I get:

```
$ ls -l
total 169176
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   237757 Apr 16 07:44 config-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   237757 Jul 13 10:52 config-5.4.0-80-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   237757 Jul 23 05:56 config-5.4.0-81-generic
drwx------ 3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Aug 19 11:17 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43261536 Jul 22 09:33 initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43267722 Jul 23 10:31 initrd.img-5.4.0-80-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43266831 Aug 17 11:26 initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  4586616 Apr 16 07:44 System.map-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4587397 Jul 13 10:52 System.map-5.4.0-80-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  4587874 Jul 23 05:56 System.map-5.4.0-81-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  9449728 Apr 16 07:44 vmlinuz-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  9453824 Jul 13 11:28 vmlinuz-5.4.0-80-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  9457920 Jul 23 05:59 vmlinuz-5.4.0-81-generic
```

So once again `vmlinuz` ending in `73`, `80`, and `81` are present but not the `70` that grub seems to be looking for.  I also checked `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and it also has entries for `73`, `80`, and `81` but not `70`!  Where is grub getting `70` from?

Based on some other posts I also tried pressing `c` from the grub main menu to do a terminal session, I found the following information but I'm not sure what do to, sorry this pic is a bit blurry:

[image]

I'm not sure how to enter a command here to resolve this if that is possible.

One more thing I should mention is after doing the advanced boot option to get back into Ubuntu 18.04 I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

hoping that these would resolve the concern but they did not.  Suggestions ??

-- Response to @heynnema --

here is my terminal output from your suggested command:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-81-generic
[sudo] password for cdahms: 
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
```

After reboot result is same as before (same error with usual 18.04 boot menu choice, still works with advanced options choice)

-- 2nd Response to @heynnema --

`fdisk`:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 32.3 MiB, 33865728 bytes, 66144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 704 KiB, 720896 bytes, 1408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 243.9 MiB, 255762432 bytes, 499536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 276 KiB, 282624 bytes, 552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 2.5 MiB, 2621440 bytes, 5120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 32.3 MiB, 33853440 bytes, 66120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 2.4 MiB, 2555904 bytes, 4992 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 61.7 MiB, 64729088 bytes, 126424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 63850E58-ACD2-4B55-B5D5-29E46C830D03

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1050624 2029461901 2028411278 967.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2029463552 4000796671 1971333120   940G Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/loop8: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 548 KiB, 561152 bytes, 1096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 2.5 MiB, 2605056 bytes, 5088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 2.2 MiB, 2342912 bytes, 4576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 219 MiB, 229629952 bytes, 448496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 64.8 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 548 KiB, 561152 bytes, 1096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 55.4 MiB, 58130432 bytes, 113536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 55.5 MiB, 58134528 bytes, 113544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 61.8 MiB, 64770048 bytes, 126504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

`blkid`:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="63850e58-acd2-4b55-b5d5-29e46c830d03" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="B97B-4975" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="b1d40bc5-1bc0-490b-92d4-256bad74c673"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="cdc92bbb-f4d8-4a31-9cbf-5215632adb49" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3079da12-a09d-4a1a-a21a-61af34810c23"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="93b02138-35e3-4446-a2b9-e16cf6c22786" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="51df7e8c-fa57-4275-9348-27902134ee6a"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Based on one of the answers to this post [How can I detect whether my disk is using GPT or MBR from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387351/how-can-i-detect-whether-my-disk-is-using-gpt-or-mbr-from-a-terminal) I did:

```
$ sudo ls
 aws                  IntelliScan_Haze_Class_005   pycharm
 awscliv2.zip             IntelliScan_Images_005       rotated_IntelliScan_Images_007
 Desktop              IntelliScan_Images_006       snap
 Documents            IntelliScan_Images_007       temp
 Downloads            minicom.log          temp2.txt
 Downloads2           Music            Templates
 Dropbox             'Nala devices'        temp.txt
 eclipse              Nala_PVT3_2mm_lens_haze      Videos
 examples.desktop         Pictures            'Volumetric Dummy Devices.txt'
 IntelliScan_Haze_Class_001   Public               workspace-apps
 IntelliScan_Haze_Class_002   PVT3_haze            workspace-prod
 IntelliScan_Haze_Class_003   PVT4
 IntelliScan_Haze_Class_004  'PVT4 IMEIs.txt'
```

then:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l | grep -B 5 Disklabel

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.9 TiB, 2048408248320 bytes, 4000797360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
```

So it seems I'm using GPT formatting

-- 3rd Response to @heynnema --

Yes I did use `Grub Customizer`, did that jack things up?  I've heard it can do that but I've never had a problem before.  Here is my `ls -al /etc/grub.d`:

```
$ ls -al /etc/grub.d
total 100
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Aug 19 11:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root 12288 Aug 19 10:32 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10046 Jul 30  2020 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  6258 Jul 20  2020 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   914 May 23 22:55 10_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   221 May 23 22:55 40_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   914 May 23 22:55 41_linux_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 11298 Jul 30  2020 44_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1992 Jan 28  2016 45_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1539 May 23 22:55 46_os-prober_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1418 Jul 30  2020 47_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   285 May 23 22:55 48_custom_proxy
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   216 Jul 30  2020 49_custom
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 23 22:55 backup
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 23 22:55 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 23 22:55 proxifiedScripts
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   483 Jul 30  2020 README
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   272 May 23 22:55 .script_sources.txt
```

-- 4th Response to @heynnema --
`grep -i 5.4.0-70 /etc/grub.d/*`:

```
$ grep -i 5.4.0-70 /etc/grub.d/*
/etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy:-'SUBMENU' as 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'{-'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/*, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-73-generic'~408f07b7e0dd8d620374c5b681855861~, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-73-generic (recovery mode)'~003de087994ae2af14e29d21bf9905b2~, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic'~c5a297cf454d7588afd791e38e600c79~, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic (recovery mode)'~fdd81b462724bdc5fe27e5506ee615f4~, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic'~6f6c570f06cb15f97ea26de817f5f40a~, -'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic (recovery mode)'~6b0d22eb9c2641ea1add550c2162c631~}
/etc/grub.d/41_linux_proxy:+'SUBMENU' as 'Advanced options for Ubuntu'{+'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/*, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-73-generic'~408f07b7e0dd8d620374c5b681855861~, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-73-generic (recovery mode)'~003de087994ae2af14e29d21bf9905b2~, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic'~c5a297cf454d7588afd791e38e600c79~, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic (recovery mode)'~fdd81b462724bdc5fe27e5506ee615f4~, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic'~6f6c570f06cb15f97ea26de817f5f40a~, +'Advanced options for Ubuntu'/'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-70-generic (recovery mode)'~6b0d22eb9c2641ea1add550c2162c631~}
grep: /etc/grub.d/backup: Is a directory
grep: /etc/grub.d/bin: Is a directory
grep: /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts: Is a directory
```

It seems 5.4.0-70 is in grub.d!! Perhaps this is the problem?

`cat /etc/fstab`:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=cdc92bbb-f4d8-4a31-9cbf-5215632adb49 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=B97B-4975  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

-- 5th Response to @heynnema --

Here is my Grub Customizer edit screen for the regular Ubuntu 18.04 menu item:

[image]

I don't understand this b/c `-73` is here not `-70` ?!?!

-- 6th Response to @heynnema --

Main Grub Customizer screen:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything shared between 20.04 and 18.04? You're missing some symlinks in /boot. Did you delete them? It's possible that your ramdisk file needs to be rebuilt. Boot to 18.04, open `terminal`, and type `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-81-generic`, then `reboot`. Report back.

Comment: To my knowledge nothing is shared and I'm sure I did not delete anything in /boot.  I'll try your command.

Comment: updated question with terminal output for your suggested command, no change

Comment: What's on hd0? Are both 20.04 and 18.04 on hd1? Are both drives internal drives?

Comment: When I installed I installed Ubuntu 20.04 first with mostly default install options, then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with mostly default options, choosing to split the HD about 50/50 between them.  There is only one HD in the machine, the 2 TB M.2.  I'm not sure what hd0 is, I would suppose it's the boot partition created by the Ubuntu installer.  The one HD is the only drive present, there are no external drives.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid`. Is your 2 TB formatted GPT or MBR?

Comment: Updated question with fdisk and blkid output, I'm using GPT formatting, also edited question for this

Comment: Did you use `GRUB Customizer`? Show me `ls -al /etc/grub.d`.

Comment: Show me `grep -i 5.4.0-70 /etc/grub.d/*` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: just added ls -al /etc/grub.d to question

Comment: just added grep -i 5.4.0-70 /etc/grub.d/* and cat /etc/fstab

Comment: I still have the thumb drives I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 from, I made them via usual download and thumb drive prep process as instructed on the Ubuntu website.

Comment: We found the problem. `GRUB Customizer` probably did the deed. Bring it up and check for a custom entry for -70.

Comment: grub costumizer is a pain.  `mkdir $HOME/grub-bak` Move any files with proxy in name to this created folder. Also mv folder `bin` and `backup` and file `proxifiedScripts`  from `/etc/grub.d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default GRUB boot was looking for kernel vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic which doesn't exist.

The **Additional Options** boot was correctly showing kernels -73, -80, and -81.

`GRUB Customizer` was used to tailor the GRUB menu, and it screwed up. Review the `GRUB Customizer` menus looking for a custom entry for -70, or for a way to revert back to the standard GRUB menus.

Comment: Just posted my Grub Customizer screen for the Ubuntu 18.04 menu entry in the question, there is an entry for -73 but not -70 so I'm still not sure where the -70 is comming from.  I'll accept your answer though since at this point I can just manually change it to -81 in those 2 grub.d files

Comment: @cdahms  If you look on the screen directly behind what you just posted, does -70 show up there?

Comment: @cdahms In `GRUB Customizer`, is there a choice to reset the GRUB menus back to default?

Comment: There is a "Revert" button but that only reverts the list to the default order.  I'll post the Grub Customizer screenshot without the pop-up

Comment: I'll keep poking around in Grub Customizer and researching this, bottom line it's a Grub Customizer bug

Comment: @cdahms Yes. Please keep me posted.

Comment: @cdahms Status please...

Comment: still working on it, using advanced options menu to boot for now

Comment: @cdahms I would try the REVERT in GRUB Customizer.